# heroku pg:psql not working [connection refused]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am running a Ruby on Rails app on Heroku with Postgres Database.
I used to be able to connect to my database from my terminal using `heroku pg:psql` command

Recently, things have changed. After running `heroku pg:psql` command, I get the following error.

```
--> Connecting to postgresql-perpendicular-94363
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "ec2-23-23-130-158.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (23.23.130.158) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried to search online about it, but nothing useful has been found.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Based on your username, I'm guessing you're a student. Are you trying these commands from a campus network? High probability that this error is caused by a firewall blocking 5432.

Comment: @RangerRanger You are absolutely right. School network is blocking the access. Using my phone's hotspot, this command work perfectly. Thanks No idea why the school will block it.

Comment: It's a pretty standard network security posture to assume. Block everything unless there is a good reason to open it.

Comment: @RangerRanger Running my traffic through a VPN caused this same error. Only thanks to your comment about networks being blocked did I figure this out. Turning off the VPN fixed the error.

Answer (score 2):

I've just tried connect to your database:

```
psql "dbname=postgresql-perpendicular-94363 host=ec2-23-23-130-158.compute-1.amazonaws.com user=test_user port=5432 sslmode=require"
```

And I've got:

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "test_user"
```

Because, of course I don't know you credentials :)
However, it seems that connection works. I suppose, that you forgot set `sslmode`. As you can see in [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress), it is required:

> All connections require SSL: sslmode=require.

Update:

I've checked connection without `sslmode`, and message is other than yours:

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "31.42.24.63", user "test_user", database "postgresql-perpendicular-94363", SSL off
```

So, I suppose that this is a problem with you internet connection. Check you firewall setup.

Comment: You are absolutely right. This command has no problem. My school's internet is blocking this access for some reason. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

As per the description mentioned in the post, the way you have specified is correct.
Moreover you can also try the below mentioned command where you specify the database as well.

```
heroku pg:psql DATABASE_URL
```

Note: This is only used when there are multiple databases linked.

Comment: So, how does your answer solve the problem? `heroku pg:psql DATABASE_URL` also gives the same error. Thanks.